# E.F Core 6 Error insert many to many error inserted into the identity column of table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-6.0

I have some many-to-many tables and when I save to the database I get the following error.

```
public class SwUCard
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
    public string? NameEs { get; set; }
     
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
    public string? NameEn { get; set; }
     
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(250)")]
    public string? SubtitleEs { get; set; }  
     
    public ICollection<SwUTrait> Traits { get; set; } 
}

public class SwUTrait

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string NameEs { get; set; }
    
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<SwUCard> Cards { get; set; }
}

public SwUCardDto Add(SwUCardDto t) 
    
    var d = t.Adapt<SwUCard>();
    _context.SwUCard.Add(d);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    SwUCard dbObjectResult = _context.Set<SwUCard>().Local.LastOrDefault();
    return new ContextToApp.GenericMapper<SwUCard, SwUCardDto>().Create(dbObjectResult);
```

I create the swucard entity and add the SwUTrait list that is in the database and recover it and insert it into the new swucard entity

the mistake is:

> An explicit value cannot be inserted into the identity column of table '`SwUTrait`' when IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF.

Answer (score 0):

> An explicit value cannot be inserted into the identity column of table
> 'SwUTrait' when IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF.

Well based on your description and scenario, the error you are getting that indicates that you're trying to set the `Id` property of an existing `SwUTrait` entity before adding it to the `SwUCard`.Traits collection, which violates a database constraint.

As you may know, when you create a new `SwUCard` entity, you populate its Traits collection with existing SwUTrait objects retrieved from the database.
Since these SwUTrait objects already have their Id properties set (presumably auto-generated by the database), attempting to add them to the Traits collection again forces EF Core to insert them into the database again, even though they already exist.

In order to fix the issue,  you can do following modification:

```
public SwUCardDto Add(SwUCardDto t) 
{
    var d = t.Adapt<SwUCard>();

    foreach(var trait in d.Traits)
    {
        trait.Id = 0; 
    }

    d.Traits = d.Traits.Distinct().ToList();

    _context.SwUCard.Add(d);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    SwUCard dbObjectResult = _context.Set<SwUCard>().Local.LastOrDefault();
    return new ContextToApp.GenericMapper<SwUCard, SwUCardDto>().Create(dbObjectResult);
}
```

**Note:** By ensuring that the Id property of SwUTrait entities is not explicitly set before saving changes, EF Core should handle the identity column generation correctly.Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#overriding-value-generation) for more details.

Comment: I have changed the code but it puts duplicates in DB

Comment: Well, first of all, the exception has not been thrown, regarding the duplication, could you please explain a bit more, what is redundant? Even that is duplicate, we can set conditional for that if exist kind of. However, if you could share more details we could exactly investigate that.

Comment: Well, first of all, the exception has not been thrown, regarding the duplication, could you please explain a bit more, what is redundant? Even that is duplicate, we can set conditional for that  you can write this before insertion`d.Traits = d.Traits.Distinct().ToList();`. However, if you could share more details we could exactly investigate that. See the updated answer

Comment: I have explained myself poorly, it does not insert duplicates but if I set the value 0 it inserts a new record in the daughter table into the DB and what they have to do is a reference to a record already created previously.